# Extended generic parameter of class method dont build

Tags: angular, typescript

I got an issue while building an angular project with `ng build`.

```
public update (item: T extends IModel): Observable<T> {
  return this.http.put<any>(`${this.api}/${this.resource}/${item.id}`, item);
}
```

It say, it expect a ',' in `(item: T extends IModel)`.

Any idea how to make it build?
It works well with `ng serve` and to looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks

I just found a way. What i have done:

```
export class ResourceService<T extends IModel> {
   ...

  public update (item: T): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.put<any>(`${this.api}/${this.resource}/${item.id}`, item);
  }
}
```

My interface is:

```
 export interface IModel {
  id: string;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the type parameter like this:

```
public update<T extends IModel>(item: T): Observable<T> {
  return this.http.put<any>(`${this.api}/${this.resource}/${item.id}`, item);
}
```